# libGDX - How can I access my DesktopLauncher class from ApplicationAdapter?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to create map creation tool for my libGDX games. And I am using swing and libgdx together. I don't have a problem about canvas displaying. And I can create an ApplicationAdaptor as a field of DesktopLauncher. And I can reach ApplicationAdapter's methods without any problem. But I can't reach DesktopLauncher from ApplicationAdapter. It's like not defined any class.

Here it's not a problem :

```
public class DesktopLauncher extends JFrame {
    EOEditor editor; // It's my ApplicationAdapter
}
```

Here it's a problem :

```
public class EOEditor extends ApplicationAdapter {
    DesktopLauncher launcher;
}
```

Sorry for my English it is not my main language. And thank you for answers. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Can you tell us what module each class is in? Classes in the `core` module cannot access classes in the `desktop` module. My guess is that's why you cannot access certain classes you've made.

Comment: DesktopLauncher is in desktop module. ApplicationAdapter is in core module. I understand but at the same time how could i access my ApplicationAdapter from DesktopLauncher? And have you any advice for this problem? What can i do?

Comment: This article in the wiki documentation explains the typical solution to this problem. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code Basically, create an interface in the `core` module that has the desktop methods you need, and get an instance of it in your game constructor. And then in the `desktop` module, implement the interface and pass the implementation to your game constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much.